# Angular 4 in JS Fiddle - Cannot resolve dependecy

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, jsfiddle

I made a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4x29stma/) for Angular 4 app and when I try to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in `Child` component:

```
public constructor(
    private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

I get error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChildComponent: (?).

I can't inject any service from `"@angular/core"`.

When I delete constructor or `ChangeDetectorRef` injection everything works fine.

How can I inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in my component?

Thanks

Comment: a problem with JSFiddle itself, in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w83drk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) it works

Comment: @selemmn, thanks, you are right. You can post it as answer and a will accept it

Comment: Thanks, done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with `JSFiddle` itself, in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w83drk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) it works fine.